# how can i implement android animation of printing a receipt like on MobilePay?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, animation, effect

I am building a POS android app and like to implement an animation of a receipt printing. Similar to that in MobilPay https://youtu.be/2B4992fh-pA . I cant seem to know where to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a Animation folder in your project and put the code there(res->animation). these links may help you out,

https://github.com/2359media/EasyAndroidAnimations
https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

Comment: Though i can't get how exactly am going to do the editable receipt paper like part cause i know with it i can use the animations to animate it. useful library nevertheless.